# Javascript: Using a pre-existent object values as keys os a new one

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I created this object:

```
var keys = {A: 'a', B: 'b' };
```

Later I tried create this other object:

```
var values = {keys.A: 1, keys.B: 2};
```

However I got this in Firefox console:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

Even when I tried:

```
var vals = {keys['A']: 1, keys['B']: 2}
```

I got the same error.

The only way to get a success is if I type this:

```
var vals= {};
vals[keys.A] = 1;
vals[keys.B] = 2;
```

So, my question is if there is a more elegant way (similar to the first try) to create an anonymous object using as keys the values from a pre-existent object.

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: In Object literals, property names must either be string literals (e.g. `'keys.A'`) or valid identifiers. `keys.A` is not a valid identifier, the tokeniser splits `keys` and `.`, so the parser sees an identifier followed by a period where it expects a colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the more elegant way is to use ES6 syntax:

```
var values = {[keys.A]: 1, [keys.B]: 2};
```

The thing in brackets can be any expression, so run wild:

```
var values = { [createPropName() + "_prop"]: 42 }
```

This is called "computed (dynamic) property names". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have to use the ES5.

Comment: There are an increasing number of toolings available for using ES6, so it's no longer really a technical problem.

Comment: @torazaburo—but it is a practical problem.

Answer (score 2):

## try this

```
var keys = {A: 'a', B: 'b' },
    foo = {};

for (key in keys) { foo[key] = keys[key] }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant to the OP's question. He doesn't want to copy the property values into `foo`; he wants to set properties **on** `foo`, whose names are found as the values in `keys`, to some other values.

Comment: The OP wants an object literal that uses expressions for keys. That is only possible in browsers compliant with [*ECMAScript Ed 6 draft Object Initiliser*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer) which supports *ComputedPropertyName* syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In an [*Object Initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), the property name must be one of:

- IdentifierName
- StringLiteral
- NumericLiteral

You can do what you want in ES5 using an Object literal for the keys and an Array literal for the values:

```
var keys = {A: 'a', B: 'b' };
var values = [1, 2];
var obj = {};

Object.keys(keys).forEach(function(v, i) {
  obj[v] = values[i];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) // {"A":1,"B":2}
```

However, that isn't reliable because the object properties may not be returned in the order you expect, so you might get:

```
{"B":1,"A":2};
```

To do what you want in ES5 and guarantee the order, an array of keys and an array of values is required, so something like:

```
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var values = [1, 2, 3];
var obj = {};
keys.forEach(function(v, i) {obj[v] = values[i]});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) // {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```